# Is there a way in JSF to right-align numbers (such as currency and percentage) in table columns without manipulating each column with css?

Tags: html, jsf, numbers, alignment

I try to right-align all numbers in table columns. Is there a functionality in JSF or Primefaces that automatically align numbers to the right? I want an automated and more compact solution than adding css to each column.

Comment: Why not css? You'd do this the same as in plain html. JSF is in this regard nothing more than an html generator.  How would you do it in 'html' when not using css? And what is adding css not a way of automation? I really fail to see your approach and what you think makes your non-css way easier??? I think it makes it more complex...

Comment: And if you don't want to use CSS, css can never be a part of your problem and hence the css tag on the question is wrong (as is JSF in this case in my opinion) and off-topic: did a co-worker upvote this question?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer @Kukeltje. I agree with you, the question was a little bit hard to understand, because i was not opposed to use CSS. Sorry for that. It's quite easy to use css tags like "float" or "text-align" to get what I want. I thought maybe there is a function in Primefaces, that you can mark the column as "curreny"(for example) , that automatically get preferences like patterns etc. 

And nobody upvoted this question, why?